# How to get the newest table from dynamodb?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm writing a project which has a python script that create a new table and pass json data to the dynamodb every 6 hours, and has a node js server to read data from dynamodb when is requested. Since the dynamodb will have a new table every 6 hours, how does the node js server read the newest updated table? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: why not make the table names deterministic, based on time, or a round-robin type of scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a combination of [list table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.htm) and [describe table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html).

The first should give you a list of all tables, on which you can then run describe tables to get [CreationDateTime](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TableDescription.html#DDB-Type-TableDescription-CreationDateTime).

Code here on AWS [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.JsShell.02.html) should get you started.